# How to see the CSS files loaded in a page in Google Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

How can I see the CSS files loaded in a page in Google Chrome? I can see the JS files, but not the CSS.

Comment: This is available in Developer Tools -> Resources -> Stylesheets (you'll probably have to turn on resource tracking for the session), but this is probably a SuperUser-type question.

Comment: It doesn't work in some cases

Comment: There is a great chrome extension called CSS Used - you can copy the CSS of an element and all of it's descendants...quite useful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the Network tab and filter for CSS requests in the Chrome Developer Console.

Comment: Is there a way to download CSS file ?

Comment: @vikramvi: It's a network request, so you can right-click on the file you want and `Copy` – `Copy content` or, as with any other network request, click on the request you want to inspect and navigate to the `Preview` (parsed/beautified) or raw `Response` tab to see the content.

Answer (score 12):

**Warning: this answer is now outdated! For recent versions of Chrome, check Dr1Ku's answer.**

On Chrome's Developer Tools tab (CTRL + SHIFT + I), go to **Resources** (you may have to enable Resource tracking on that page), and click on the sub-tab **Stylesheets**. That will show all css files loaded by that page.

Answer (score 6):

I order to see what files have been loaded right click on a blank section on the page, and select **View Page Source**. From here it will show you the HTML page as it was rendered by Chrome.

If you look in the header section you should be a list of all external file that were called in as well, and they should be hyperlinks, just click on any of them and Chrome will show that that specific file in a new tab.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested there is a way to look for them in JS:

(Please use a modern browser)

```
var sts = document.styleSheets;
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
    var st = sts.item(i);
    if (st && st.href) {
       result.push(st.href.match(/\w*\.css/));
    }
}
console.dir(result);
```

Comment: Tried on this page in Chrome and it gives an error:
VM333:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
    at <anonymous>:5:25
(anonymous) @ VM333:5

Comment: Please check again. I did a little change.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click anywhere on the page and select "Inspect element". From there, you'll want to click the Resources tab and tell Chrome if it should always enable that panel or just once for the session (choose whichever you prefer).  Once inside, you'll see all the files on the left. You can view the content by clicking the tiny Content tab next to Headers on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CSS Used](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff?hl=en) "Get all css rules used by the selected DOM and its descendants.
"

I found this helpful for getting the CSS and inspecting it in my code editor.

Tips:

- Copy the CSS from `CSS Used` into your code editor, prettify it, and read away!