# Facebook app, display a wallpost-like UI

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbml, facebook-fbml

In FBML they have this fb:wallpost tag which I can use to display a wall post, but they said it's deprecated.

Is there any other alternative to display a facebook post with full features such as comment and like button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the [`fb:wallpost`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/wallpost/) [FBML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) tag made the rendering of a wall-style post possible. The FBML purpose was to emulate the native Facebook rendering on your own app. Here is what they offer now:

> You can use our [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and [Social Plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/plugins) to embedded many of
>   the same social features which were available in FBML.

*Many of the same*, but not all of them. And particularly not an alternative to `fb:wallpost`.

Let's say that what they supply instead hasn't really the same purpose that had FBML. It's not about UI anymore. Now, it's not Facebook which is helping *you* to **render** the existing  content, but it's *you* who helps Facebook to **increase** its traffic when your app brings social interactions. If we look at what they provide, we've got only interaction enhancers like: follow, like, comments, recommendations, login, registration.

We understand that they don't want us to make a dupe of their content, but they favor *further* social activities.

Their political consulting change and you have to do with it.

By the way, it's not worth to look for plugins or templates that you might find on the net (or even to make your own), because it's forbidden to reproduce one's design. Speaking about that: [Before you go ahead and copy Facebook's look, be aware of any legal implications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670719/1515819). Anyway, you can still find some [nice ways](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/) to display the API's content.

Comment: I hate it when they just deprecated something and does not give any alternative approach at all given any reason ..