# View CSS added by via inspector in Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

First, I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661665/can-you-add-new-css-properties-in-chrome-inspector) exists, but it's not what I'm getting at.  I want to know if there is some view in Developer Tools that lets you see *all* styles added "via inspector."  [For example](http://screencast.com/t/iaiOxBYeR), I can select the span.count element and see this is something I added.

But I've added lots of stuff via inspector.  Right now I have to click on each element to see if it's one of the elements that I added a style for.

Anyone seen an SO post for this already or know the answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a useful note for some readers: solutions mentioned here apply *only* to styles *added*. Not to *existing* selectors that have added/changed properties.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3936196/632951

Comment: I'm here because I added probably 25+ style rules via an inspector stylesheet and then refreshed the page before copying them to my CSS file 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since at least Chrome 22, you can open the "inspector-stylesheet" source in the Sources panel. It contains all the rules you have added manually.

Comment: Yup and it's there for Chrome 21 too: http://screencast.com/t/iglPzUkrsycR

I just did an update over Chrome 20, so I can't say whether or not it was in that version.  I know that it didn't have this text link in the Elements panel:
http://screencast.com/t/jVy3YqUQ

Thanks!  And thank you Google Chrome for adding this feature!

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to file DevTools feature requests at http://new.crbug.com (start your summary with the string "DevTools: " for better triaging).

Comment: This seems to now have disappeared with Chrome 23.  Can anyone confirm or deny that?

Comment: Still present in Chrome 24... If you have several frames in the page, you should look for the resource in the folder corresponding to the frame containing your focused element.

Comment: This definitely seems to be missing in Chrome 25, not visible either in Resources, Sources, nor via the "local modifications" menuitem.

Found [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160974&q=inspector%20stylesheet&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) on chrome bugtracker and will track through there.

Comment: Chrome 40 has it, it's possible you were looking for the "+" button in Elements > Styles (on the top right)

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is coming across this question and still having trouble with newer versions of chrome this worked for me:
Add a style in the elements panel on an element, then in the elements panel within the css rules, click on the inspector-stylesheet link. This will open the inspector stylesheet in the sources panel. You can leave it open there and add to it as needed.

Comment: I do this so often, I wish I could just go to sources and launch a new inspector stylesheet without having to go to the elements tab.

If anyone knows how to do this, please share!